# Expected size of cookie that is halved 50% of the time someone passes by it

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification, expected-value

> I have a really big cookie that I leave in a hallway. People pass by
> the cookie in the hallway. With probability $\frac 12$, each passerby
> eats $\frac 13$ of the remaining cookie (with probability $\frac 12$
> the passerby does nothing). After $n$ people pass by, what's the
> expected size [ratio] of the cookie?

I used two approaches, but got different answers.

First, I thought that after $n$ people pass by, in expectation $n/2$ of them eat the cookie, so we have an expected size of $(\frac 23)^{n/2}$.

The other way I did it was computing $\sum_{k=0}^n (\frac 12)^n \binom nk(\frac 23)^k $, since for each $k$ from $0$ to $n$, there is a $(\frac 12)^n\binom nk$ probability of $k$ passersby eating the cookie, leading to a size [ratio] of $(\frac 23)^k$. But this comes out to $(\frac 56)^n$.

Which line of thinking is wrong, and why?

Comment: @Ciprum Why is the second one wrong?

Comment: For $n=1$, the expected value surely is $\frac12\cdot 1+\frac12\cdot\frac23=\frac56$, so the first attempt is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one is correct, because it uses the standard formula for the expected value of a discrete variable.

So what's wrong with the first attempt? Let $X$ be the random variable for the size of the cookie after $n$ people passing and $Y$ the random variable measuring how many people ate from the cookie. Then you argued correctly that $$\mathbb E[Y]=\frac n2\quad\text{and}\quad X=\left(\frac23\right)^Y.$$ However, this does not imply that $$\mathbb E[X]=\left(\frac23\right)^{\mathbb E[Y]}$$ because this would not take into account how $X$ changes if $Y$ takes a value other than $\mathbb E[Y]$. In this case, $X$ changes more drastically if $Y$ is smaller than $\mathbb E[Y]$, for example.

To make this more clear, let's say each person eats $90$% of the cookie, still with a $50$% chance, and $n=2$. Then there are three possible cookie sizes after the two people: $1$, $0.1$, and $0.01$. While it is true that the median is $0.1$, the change in absolute value between $1$ and $0.1$ is much larger than the one between $0.1$ and $0.01$. Since the expected value is just the weighted average of the outcomes, and $1$ and $0.01$ have the same probability of occuring, the expected value will be larger than $0.1$.

In general, if you have random variables $X,Y_1,Y_2,\ldots,Y_m$ and $X=f(Y_1,\ldots,Y_m)$ for some function $f:\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R$, you can only conclude that $\mathbb E[X]=f(\mathbb E[Y_1],\ldots,\mathbb E[Y_m])$ if $f$ is linear. (There will of course be random cases in which the formula is true by chance even if $f$ is not linear, but in general the formula is false in this case.)